# sending data to two list items in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, defaultdict

Python Script:

```
msg = """
Device: Main1
ID: 1111
status: OK

Device: Main1
ID: 2222
Status: OK

Device: Main2
ID: 3333
status: OK

Device: Main2
ID: 4444
Status: OK
"""
main1_id = []
main2_id = []

for line in msg.split("\n"):
    if  line.startswith("ID:"):
        main1_id.append(line)
print main1_id
print main2_id
```

I have msg variable data. I want to add id's of this data to two different lists `main1_id` and `main2_id` if the Device is Main1 and Main2 respectively.
I tried to implement this in above code. I stuck and I need help.

output:

```
['ID: 1111', 'ID: 2222', 'ID: 3333', 'ID: 4444']
[]
```

Expected output:

```
['ID: 1111', 'ID: 2222']
['ID: 3333', 'ID: 4444']
```

Comment: You never append something to `main2_id`. Why do you expect that it contains some items?

Comment: Do you just need the id's?

Comment: Just trying to explain requirement ..i posted question like this

Comment: @Kedar, yes only ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use a dictionary

You should try to avoid creating a variable number of variables in this way. Here you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
L = msg.split('\n')

for idx, line in enumerate(L):
    if line.startswith('Device'):
        dd[line.split(': ')[-1]].append(int(L[idx+1].split(': ')[-1]))
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(list, {'Main1': [1111, 2222],
                   'Main2': [3333, 4444]})
```

Then access your lists via `dd['Main1']` and `dd['Main2']`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a defualtdict and a basic syntax parser to handle this. Id go with something along the lines of this using regex and collections to save myself time. This code will also emit Error if the file syntax is bad which is a good thing.

```
import collections 
ids = collections.defualtdict(list)
line_regex = r"(\w*): *(\w*)"

for line in input.split():

    if not line.strip(): 
        continue

    key, value = re.match(line_regex, line).groups()
    if key == 'Device':
        cur_device = value
    if key == 'ID' and cur_device is not None:
        ids[cur_device].append(value)
        cur_device = None
    if key == 'ID' and cur_device is None:
        raise SyntaxError('Could not parse input')
```